# Azure Traffic Logs - see geography of requests

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there any way to see, on an Azure Website, a log of all the requests divided by geographic area / IP?
Today we experienced a lot of requests (4 times than the average) and I'd like to know if is some kind of DDoS or similar.
Thanks
Marco

Comment: Use Application Insights - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics

Answer (score 1):

I ended up enabling diagnostics on the application.
Go on the app, under "Monitoring" select "Diagnostics logs".

Then I enabled every kind of log with storage on the Blob.

After logs have been generated I analyzed them using "Weblog Expert".